# Is it possible to replicate to a different database name using SQL Server Alwayson Availability Groups?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

Is it possible to replicate to a different database name using SQL Server High Availability Groups?

Comment: No times fifteen characters.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik You should make that an answer... times fifteen characters ;)

Comment: @SeanGallardy I think the size of the answer matches the size of the question :D